# Flask application factory: how do we tell the app to use PostgresqlExtDatabase?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, factory, peewee

[In the peewee documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html?highlight=FTSModel#postgresql-extensions) it is stated that:

> In order to start using the features described below, you will need to use the extension **PostgresqlExtDatabase** class instead of **PostgresqlDatabase**.

Here's my app initialization code:

```
from playhouse.flask_utils import FlaskDB  

db_wrapper = FlaskDB()

def create_app(env):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # load config depending on the environment
    app.config.from_yaml(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'config.yml'), env)

    # init extensions
    db_wrapper.init_app(app)
```

Inside the **config.yml** we have:

```
COMMON: &common
  DEBUG: False
  TESTING: False

DEVELOPMENT: &development
  <<: *common
  DEBUG: True
  DATABASE: 'postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/app_db_name'
```

How do I tell the **flask app** to use the **`PostgresqlExtDatabase`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Database URL schema to `postgresext`, or `postgresext+pool` if you want to use a Connection Pool.
Examples:

```
DATABASE: 'postgresext://user:pass@localhost:5432/app_db_name'
DATABASE: 'postgresext+pool://user:pass@localhost:5432/app_db_name'
```

Reference (and a list of supported schemes): http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#db-url